# Database indexes and their Big-O notation

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, indexing, big-o

I'm trying to understand the performance of database indexes in terms of Big-O notation. Without knowing much about it, I would guess that:

- Querying on a primary key or unique index will give you a O(1) lookup time.
- Querying on a non-unique index will also give a O(1) time, albeit maybe the '1' is slower than for the unique index (?)
- Querying on a column without an index will give a O(N) lookup time (full table scan).

Is this generally correct ? Will querying on a primary key ever give worse performance than O(1) ?  My specific concern is for SQLite, but I'd be interested in knowing to what extent this varies between different databases too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Most relational databases structure indices as B-trees.

If a table has a clustering index, the data pages are stored as the leaf nodes of the B-tree. Essentially, the clustering index becomes the table.

For tables w/o a clustering index, the data pages of the table are stored in a heap. Any non-clustered indices are B-trees where the leaf node of the B-tree identifies a particular page in the heap.

The worst case height of a B-tree is O(log n), and since a search is dependent on height,  B-tree lookups run in something like (on the average)

O(log<sub>*t*</sub> n)

where t is the minimization factor ( each node must have at least *t*-1 keys and at most 2*t* -1 keys (e.g., 2*t* children).

That's the way I understand it.

And different database systems, of course, may well use different data structures under the hood.

And if the query does not use an index, of course, then the search is an iteration over the heap or B-tree containing the data pages.

Searches are a little cheaper if the index used can satisfy the query; otherwise, a lookaside to fetch the corresponding datapage in memory is required.

Answer (score 11):

The indexed queries (unique or not) are more typically O(log n).  Very simplistically, you can think of it as being similar to a binary search in a sorted array.  More accurately, it depends on the index type.  But a b-tree search, for example, is still O(log n).

If there is no index, then, yes, it is O(N).

Answer (score 5):

If you SELECT the same columns you search for then

- Primary or Unqiue will be O(log n): it's a b-tree search
- non-unique index is also O(log n) + a bit: it's a b-tree search
- no index = O(N)

If you require information from another "source" (index intersection, bookmark/key lookup etc) because the index is non-covering, then you could have O(n + log n) or O(log n + log n + log n) because of multiple index hits + intermediate sorting.

If statistics show that you require a high % of rows (eg not very selective index) then the index may be ignored and become a scan = O(n)

Answer (score 4):

Other answers give a good starting point; but I would just add that to get O(1), primary index itself would need to be hash-based (which is typically not the default choice); so more commonly it is logarithmic (B-tree).

You are correct in that secondary indexes typically have same complexity, but worse actual performance -- this because index and data are not clustered, so the constant (number of disk seeks) is bigger.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your query is.

- A condition of the form `Column = Value` allows the use of a hash-based index, which has O(1) lookup time.  However, [many databases, including SQLite, do not support them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Indexes).
- A condition using relational operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) can make use of an ordered index, typically implemented with a binary tree, which has O(log n) lookup time.
- More complicated expressions which cannot use an index require O(n) time.

Since you're primarily interested in SQLite, you might want to read its [Query Optimizer Overview](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) which explains in more detail how indexes are selected.

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question. It deserves a book to be written!
The three major things here are

- *the search algorithm* applied and
- the size of the *read blocks* to process
- the type of the index (hashed, B-Tree, or other)

**The complexity of O(1)**, in general,  is applied to *hashed indexes*, and the data that the database engine has in the cache.

Most DB engines use B-Tree indexes by default. The clustered indexes are not an exception. That's why when searching by a primary key, you should expect complexity **O(log N)**.

In [this nice article](https://under-the-hood.dev/blog/databases/database-storage-blocks-index-structure-search-complexity/) you can find more details on what is going on under the hood:
[image: Search complexity for indexed columns vs not indexed scan]